# How can I connect two input channels to the ScriptProcessorNode? (Web Audio Api, JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, web-audio-api

I am trying to implement a ScriptProcessorNode with two input and one output channels.

```
var source = new Array(2);

source[0] = context.createBufferSource();
source[0].buffer = buffer[0];

source[1] = context.createBufferSource();
source[1].buffer = buffer[1];

var test = context.createScriptProcessor(4096, 2, 1);

source[0].connect(test, 0, 0);
source[1].connect(test, 0, 1);

test.connect(context.destination);

source[0].start();
source[1].start();
```

When I run this code in Google Chrome as well as in Mozilla Firefox‎ I get the following error thrown. It tells me my `test`node has only one input channel.

```
Uncaught IndexSizeError: Failed to execute 'connect' on 'AudioNode': input index (1) exceeds number of inputs (1).
```

When I console print the number of input channels of the ScriptProcessorNode `test` I get two input channels.

```
test.onaudioprocess = function(evt){
    console.log("number of input channels: " + evt.inputBuffer.numberOfChannels);
}
```

Nevertheless connecting two nodes to the input of the `test`node does not work the way I do it. I want to program a vocoder inside the ScriptProcessorNode. How can I create a ScriptProcessorNode with two input and one output channels and connect two source nodes as input channel and the `context.destination`as output channel?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChannelMergerNode Have you considered this?

Comment: I need both input channels in the function which gets triggered by onaudioprocess to connect them in a specific way together. I could create two ScriptProcessorNodes and merge them afterwards but I do not know how to run two ScriptProcessorNodes parallel.

Comment: What I'm understanding you to say is that you want both channels processed separately? In that case you probably want https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChannelSplitterNode and two different `ScriptProcessorNode`s to process each mono audio stream.

Comment: I need to process all the samples of both inputs together. Something like `output[i] = inputOne[i] * inputTwo[i];`. What I want is a ScriptProcessorNode with two inputs and one output. If I run two `ScriptProcessorNodes`separately I don't think it is possible to take the values out of each sample of both nodes and calculate them together.

Comment: I don't think that's currently possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second parameter of `createScriptProcessor` is the number of input channels to the single input of the node, not the number of inputs to the node.

So the way to do this is to use a `ChannelMergerNode` with two inputs.  Connect your two sources to each of the inputs of the merger node.  The output of the merger should be connected to your script processor node.  The `onaudioprocess` callback will be given an `AudioBuffer` that has two channels in it.  You can then process these two channels however you want.

Comment: One thing that I think is slightly appalling about `.connect(_, _, inputIndex)` is that, if I understand it correctly, the inputIndex can **only** be used together with specifically `ChannelMergerNode`. All other node types have one or zero inputs. ChannelMergerNode is the only node type that has more than 1 input.

Comment: Yes, that was true.  But `AudioWorklets` can have more than one input.