# Web Audio API: Layout to Achieve Panning for an Arbitrary Number of Sources

Tags: javascript, audio, web, web-audio-api

I am trying to achieve user-controlled panning for any number of simultaneous web audio sources. The sources themselves are mono. I'm working in Javascript with the web audio API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API).

Currently, the problem I'm running into is that I'm trying to use a multi-channel output (one for each source), but the channel interpretation is overriding my attempts at panning (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioNode/channelInterpretation), leading me to think I'm doing something wrong architecturally.

I'd like to leave things at a mostly conceptual level here, since I believe that's where my problem lies.

**Current Setup**

My approach to this involves having one node handle all the processing for every source, called 'scriptNode' here. A number of channels equal to the number of audio sources is created, and a similarly equal number of panner nodes are created as well. The graph looks like this:

```
The bundle size (the '=' segments) is the number of channels, set to be equal to the number of sources.

scriptNode == splitter =+-- panner1 --+= merger == destination
                        \-- panner. --/
                        \-- panner. --/
                        \-- pannerN --/
```

Some miscellania, I'm calling this function to set scriptNode up:

```
scriptNode = firstPart.audioCtx.createScriptProcessor(2048, 0, numParts);
```

Where numParts is the number of sources. I'm also setting scriptNode's channelCountMode to 'explicit' and channelInterpretation to 'speakers'. One of these settings may end up being important, but I couldn't find out anything when trying to fiddle with the settings.

**The Problem**

When I actually test my code with this architecture, I will get the following behavior based on the number of parts I choose. The panning sliders are tied to the panner node's "pan" values for each respective source.

- numParts=1 : Mono output, panning with a slider doesn't do anything but affect the volume of the output (stronger toward the middle). I imagine this is a byproduct of downmixing to mono from a panner.
- numParts=2 : Stereo output, one hard left, one hard right. Panning both channels with a slider doesn't do anything.
- numParts=3 : Same as =2, but third channel is silent.
- numParts=4 : Similar to =2, now all channels work again, they are panned hard in an L/R/L/R order. Panning with a slider again doesn't do anything.

This behavior seems to fall in line with the channelInterpretation description, but what I want is to have panning work for each source separately, regardless of the number of channels I use. And I'd still like to *use* channels because each of my sources expect to write to a mono buffer.

Is there an architectural tweak I can make to keep this multi-channel strategy and achieve what I'm looking for?

**Code Snippets**

Relevant parts of current code based on my statements above alongside attempts to fix the problem.
Edit: Thanks to the comments below, I managed to find the issue. I called out the one-line fix so this code can be used as reference later.

Audio processing function. Only the first synth (source) sets up this callback:

```
function customAudioProcessCallback( audioProcessingEvent )
{
    // First synth - process audio for all synths!

    const outputBuffer = audioProcessingEvent.outputBuffer;

    for ( var i = 0; i < numParts; i++ ) {

    // Each part writes to one channel.

    synthParts[ i ].synthesize(outputBuffer.getChannelData( i ), outputBuffer.length);

    }
}
```

Relevant snippet of the play function:

```
function play()
{
    const contextClass = (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext || window.mozAudioContext || window.oAudioContext || window.msAudioContext);
    synthParts[ 0 ].audioCtx = new contextClass();

    synthParts[ 0 ].scriptNode = synthParts[ 0 ].audioCtx.createScriptProcessor ? synthParts[ 0 ].audioCtx.createScriptProcessor(2048, 0, numParts+1) : synthParts[ 0 ].audioCtx.createJavaScriptNode(2048, 0, numParts+1); // 2048, 0 input channels, ? outputs
    synthParts[ 0 ].scriptNode.onaudioprocess = customAudioProcessCallback;
    synthParts[ 0 ].scriptNode.channelCountMode = 'explicit';
    synthParts[ 0 ].scriptNode.channelInterpretation = 'speakers';

    // Set up splitter and panners for all channels
    var splitter = synthParts[ 0 ].audioCtx.createChannelSplitter( numParts+1 );

    for ( var i = 0; i < numParts; i++ ) {

        panList[ i ] = synthParts[ 0 ].audioCtx.createStereoPanner();
        panList[ i ].pan = panValues[ i ];

    }

    // Connection:
    // scriptNode -- splitter -+-- panner1 --+- destination
    //                         \-- panner. --/
    //                         \-- pannerN --/

    synthParts[ 0 ].scriptNode.connect(splitter);

    for ( var i = 0; i < numParts; i++ ) {

        splitter.connect( panList[ i ], i);

        // This line used to read: 
        //    panList[ i ].connect( synthParts[ 0 ].audioCtx.destination, 0, i );
        // However, this was connecting multiple parts to the input of the audio context destination, which is limited to 1 input. The correct call is below.
        panList[ i ].connect( synthParts[ 0 ].audioCtx.destination );

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `PannerNode` always produces stereo output.  When you connect the panner output to one of the input to a merger, the stereo output from the panner is downmixed to mono, effectively removing much of the panning effect.

Some information is missing, but I don't see why you need a merger.  You can send the stereo output from each panner directly to the destination.  The destination will mix the stereo output from each panner appropriately, preserving the panning effect.

Comment: I tried this out, but I was getting an error when trying to connect my panners. Seems like this problem's been found before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37508035/how-can-i-connect-two-input-channels-to-the-scriptprocessornode-web-audio-api (by you, even, I just noticed!). The proposal in that instance was to use a merger as I am currently, but I'm open to suggestions to circumvent this error without a merger to avoid the mono downmixing issue.

Comment: Same as the linked question's, i.e. "Uncaught IndexSizeError: Failed to execute 'connect' on 'AudioNode': input index (1) exceeds number of inputs (1)." This message is seen when attempting with two sources / two channels, both connected directly to the destination node. Specifically, this is thrown when the second channel tries to connect to the destination node. Perhaps I'm missing some way to change the channel bandwidth of the destination node?

Comment: I think to make progress, I would need to see a *simple* example of the code that causes errors. It's kind of too abstract right now to know what's causing the problem.

Comment: I appended some relevant snippets to my original question. The aforementioned error is being thrown on this line: "panList[ i ].connect( synthParts[ 0 ].audioCtx.destination, 0, i );" when i > 0.

Comment: I think you really want just `panList[i].connect(synthParts[0].audioCtx.destination)`.  What you have connects output 0 of the panner to input 1 of the destination.  But the destination only has one input (index 0), so that's where the error is.  (The console log should have given some info on this.)  Also, you normally create just one audio context instead of creating a new one every time.  (I assume `play()` is called more than once.)

Comment: That seemed to do it! With that modification, it seems to work for any number of sources now. Thanks for the guidance.